# springboot RequestScope autowiring not creating new instance for new request

Tags: spring-boot

I have a repository interface that extends the JpaRepository with the annotation @RequestScope. I want to autowire this repository into the service class.When I have printing the repository instance, the values is same for every request.It's not creating new instance for every request.I have also tried the following solutions:-

1. annotated the repository with
   @Scope (value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
2. used the  @Autowired annotaion  with type ObjectFactory
3. used the @Autowired annotaion  with type Provider
   then no change in the instance value.I am using springboot 2.7.0

I have tries the above 3 solutions but the same instance is used for every request.

```
@Repository
@Scope (value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public interface MasterRepository
    extends JpaRepository<AtlasRestInterfaceMaster,    AtlasRestInterfaceMasterPK>
{
}
@CustomLog
@Service
 public class MasterAccessorImpl implements MasterAccessor
{
 @Autowired
private transient MasterRepository masterRepository;

@Override
@TransactionAttribute (TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void createMasterTableEntry(String jsonData, String mandantId, String dataIdentifier)
{

    loggers.info(">>"+masterRepository.hashCode());
    
}
}
```

Comment: code added pls check

Comment: why would you need request scoped repository????? your database is not request scoped isnt it?

Comment: I see no reason to make an interface request scoped. If you had a custom repository with instance fields, may be. Can you explain?

Comment: Actually I have connection issue while executing this with huge request.while i checked on that the actual problem is connection is not released .so i think if i have used the request scoped here this will resolve for each request.But the request scoped is not worked with interface.

Comment: Instead of interface if I create a repository class with requestscoped and that implements the JpaRepository will create new instance at the time of autowiring.But in that case i want to implement all the methods in the intetface and need to write query for the custom method like findByToken.if any interface that extend the JpaRepository  so that i don't want to implement all these methods.but at that case the instance is same for all request.